# Elegant Object Extensions

Tags: c#, dynamic, data-structures

The question is - what is the best approach to extend some object with additional data
that is needed for the current context or scenario.

For example, I have Product class which has basic (core) properties like ID, Name and Price.
Product instances are primarily used as input/output to business layer operations and also to carry information between other application layers.

For example, when I need to list the Products in GUI with some extended information (like Manufacturer, Made In, some computed value, etc...) I usually make SP which returns set of rows and then I need to store this additional data in Project instances.
I do not want to extend the Product class with each of these additional properties (class would end up heavy and inelegant, missing primary function) and I also do not want to subclass Product to add new properties (which would raise complexity for some situations).

My idea is to place one or more complex properties (that store objects with their properties) which would store additional data used for various scenarios but I am not sure that is good solution.

What would you suggest?

Comment: You seem to want to avoid polymorphism because it would increase complexity in some situations.. can you explain your contention?

Comment: The objects is just carrying information, it would not change behavior when sub classed it would just add some additional properties. It is not an elegant solution if I would create subclass for each use object case - I would end up with dozens of classes doing same thing. To start with simple thing as naming of those subclasses and my head would explode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider constructing two classes. One, called `ProductSummary`, would contain a read-only representation of some Product data:

```
public class ProductSummary
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public double Price { get; }
}
```

A second class, called `ProductDetail`, would contain a read-write presentation of all Product data:

```
public class ProductDetail
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

    private ProductDetail()
    {
    }

    public double ComputeValue()
    {
    }

    public static ProductDetail(ProductSummary summary)
    {
        var newProduct = new ProductDetail();
        // load Product data using primary key from summary.Id      
        // populate newProduct from loaded data
        return newProduct;
    }
}
```

The `ProuctSummary` class turns out to be a lightweight, read-only container of critical Product information. A collection of `ProductSummary` data can be used to populate lists and the like.

Once a product needs to be edited, you can use the ID from a `ProductSummary` object to load a heavierweight `ProductDetail` class, which you can use for editing scenarios.

This may seem like redundant work, but consider that classes should be designed for a particular use case. If you have a use for a lightweight read-only summary class, and a separate use case for an editable class, then you might want to consider two separate classes.

Comment: Nice! based on approach I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are having the issue of Model vs ViewModel. ViewModels are useful for displaying purposes only, so it's a valid design to have viewmodels with extra properties and map the model to viewmodel at the UI level.

Comment: Yes, for some scenarios this is also a problem. I STRONGLY dislike to create the ViewModel and then copy back and forth whole bunch of properties from Model if need just one additional property which is relevant and used by View.

Comment: Right but the view model can just have the initial model as a property of the view model plus the additional required properties. You can map to properties of properties in a view model for a UI so you shouldn't need to make separate properties for those.

Comment: The mapping could be optimized, or there are automappers out there which can help you with manual mapping. But viewmodels are used for scenarios like you have where you need to display something different on the UI from the data of the model, but it's not exactly what is in the model, or where two different UIs may use the same data to display it in different ways.

Comment: Good, this seems like nice and clean to me.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would extend the class, but you could also do something along the lines of:

```
public class Product
{
    ...

    public List<ProductProperty> AdditionalProperties { get; set; }
}

class ProductProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

Keep in mind, definitely not best practice ;)

Answer (score 0):

So...if I understand this correcty:

- You do NOT want to extend the product class into subclasses which inherit "Product"
- You do NOT want to add all the extra "situational" properties into the Product class itself

Given this, what you are looking for is a way to add temporary properties to an object on a situational basis?

I would recommend a standard simple HashTable extension for "custom properties".

```
private HashTable CustomProperties { get; set; }

//Note: all three of these functions are unecessary if you make the hashtable public, but they do look good as far as an interface goes.
public void AddCustomProperty (String key, Object value)
{
    CustomProperties.Add(key, value);
}

public void RemoveCustomProperty (String key)
{
    CustomProperties.Remove(key);
}

public object GetCustomProperty (String key)
{
    return CustomProperties[key];
}
```

This lets you store any property you want, directly into the Products object, as a KeyValue pair.  Now, displaying them gets a lot more interesting because you can't use direct databinding anymore...same with editing.  But setting boxes and labels directly is easy enough.

An Alternative solution - **RUNTIME TYPES**

declare a custom type that doesnt really exist, but can be used like it does.

```
var ExtProduct = new {
    MyCustomProp = "whatever I want",
    ProductBase = productInstace };
```

extend as necessary.

you can also do this with lists

```
var ExtProductList = from a in ProductList select new {
    MyCustomProp = "Whatever I want",
    ProductBase = a };
```

this is a very temporary thing that is almost useless when it comes to passing the values around to other things, but has massive utility for custom calculations from join lists or UI display of temporary values.  They are a little harder to capture when you need the custom values to be editable, but not significantly so.